# Need help understanding dynamic menus in my C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to design a console application where the menus are generated from a data structure of some sort and each menu item can have a handler/action specified (which could just be displaying a different menu). Sorry if this is sounding convoluted already!

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out the correct way to go about this. It's my first C# application and I feel like I've been reading about delegates for hours and I'm still not even sure if I'm supposed to be using them.

I have a lot of existing code but I feel like it might be better if I get some overall direction before trying to fix what's potentially broken at the foundations. I'll try to describe what I'm trying to do:

- Have a "Menu" class made up of a menu heading and an arbitrary number of menu items.
- Each "MenuItem" is made up of a hotkey, description and "pointer to a handler".
- Handler does the work and returns back to the menu.

It's this "pointer to a handler" that I'm having trouble with. How should this handler be represented in the MenuItem object? How can I call the handler from the menu prompt? Am I going about it in a completely wrong way?

Hopefully this makes sense :)

Comment: @EZI I've used Events in Java before but that would mean having to setup listeners, etc. I'd like to achieve it with something like function call-backs or something along those lines. Is firing off events how you would achieve this?

Comment: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html  ,       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable

Comment: You might want to consider decision trees or finite state machines. There is plenty of examples on the web, including quite a few decent NuGet packages.

Comment: Another option, if you want it be infinitely extendable, is Managed Extensibility Framework.

Comment: Sounds like good old Turbo Vision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think delegates might be good starting point. First, because they are fairly popular in C# and since you are started to learn C# it can be a good practice. Secondly, implementing your application using delegates should be fairly straightforward.

Let's consider `Action<T>` and `Func<T>` delegates. First one can perform some action but will not return any value. Second one returns some value of type T. Both types can take up to 16 parameters. Basically their main behavior is to be a placeholder for a method.

So let's take a look at some example, embedded in the context of your application:

```
public class MenuItem<T>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public char HotKey { get; set; }
    public Func<T> FirstHandler { get; set; }       // returns some value
    public Action<T> SecondHandler { get; set; }    // does not return any value

    // let's use this method to invoke the first handler
    public T DoSomething()
    {
        // this handler is of type Func<T> so it will return a value of type T
        return this.FirstHandler.Invoke();
    }

    // let's use this method to invoke the second handler
    public void DoSomethingElse(T input)
    {
        this.SecondHandler.Invoke(input);
    }
}
```

In case of `Func` if it has more than one argument than the last one is return type. Others are input types. So for instance `Func<int, char, string>` will accept a method that takes `int` and `char` as an input but returns `string`. You get some help from Visual Studio - in the delegate description it displays `in` and `out` words in front of the parameters to signal whether it's input or output parameter.

Now, having the `MenuItem` class created you can use it in the following way:

```
class Program
{
    // A method that takes no input arguments but returns string
    private static string ReturnHelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MenuItem<string> menuItem = new MenuItem<string>();

        // FirstHandler signature is Func<T>
        // So it doesn't take any input arguments
        // and returns T - in our case string
        menuItem.FirstHandler = ReturnHelloWorld;

        // SecondHandler signature is Action<T>
        // So it takes one input argument of type T (here, string)
        // and returns void
        menuItem.SecondHandler = Console.WriteLine;

        // Now use a method of MenuItem class to invoke FirstHandler.
        string menuItemMessage = menuItem.DoSomething();
        // Use another method to invoke SecondHandler.
        menuItem.DoSomethingElse(menuItemMessage);
    }
}
```

Note that it's only a very elementary starting point for your problem. But it allows you to create menu items and assign different behaviours to the items.